# StartActivity в свернутом состоянии

Tags: android

Есть активити А, сервис и активити Б, из А я запускаю сервис, загружаю данные, по завершению операции запускаю активити Б. Если в процессе загрузки свернуть приложение, то по завершению, запуститься активити Б и приложение развернется. Как этого избежать? Как сделать, что бы активити запустилось, но в фоне!

Comment: Что означает запустить "скрыто" Activity?

Comment: @katso, если Activity свёрнуто, то система не гарантирует, что оно уже не удалено для освобождения ресурсов. Придумайте что-то другое. Объясните подробнее, какой результат хотите получить.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, когда я использовал асинктаск, я сворачивал приложение, разворачивал и активити Б, уже было запущено, а сейчас я сворачиваю, жду и вижу как стартует активити Б!

Comment: @katso, Вас не смущает, что у Вашего вопроса рейтинг "-1"? Может всё-таки нужно пересмотреть механизм?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, эм, то что вы поставили мне минус еще не говорит о том, что мне нужно пересматривать механизм! Да собственно механизм чего? Механизм запуска акитивити? Что может быть логичнее - после авторизации запустить активити с контентом?

Comment: @katso, я не минусовал. Это чей-то другой голос. А по теме - запускать после авторизации нужно новое Activity с подготовленными данными. А сами данные нужно грузить, например, в Service.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit,читайте вопрос внимательно!

Comment: Совсем не понятно зачем вам запускать Activity в свернутом виде. Какие из этого плюсы можно извлечь? Почему именно в свернутом? Почему проверку результата операции нельзя запустить при следующем запуске приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну , если не хочется переделывать программу свою, но сильно хочется результата, есть путь - 
методом startService() повесь флаг своему сервису который означал бы ЧТО НЕЛЬЗЯ запускать активити Б. К момент завершения загрузки твоей инфы , сервис читает флаг и решает что делать - запускать активити Б или нет. Флаг повесь например в момент закрытия/сворачивания активити А. И в момент открытия активи А ты снова вешаеш флаг своему сервису, который вигнализирует что МОЖНО запускать актитвити Б после загрузки. Это конечно попахивает асинхронным быдлокодом, так что я бы на твоем месте пересмотрел политику "2 активности, 1 сервис"